# Why is the Scanner .next() method returning null?

Tags: java

I am reading input from 2 separate files using 2 different Scanner objects. I have 2 nested loops whose continuing condition depends on what the Scanner's .hasNext() method returns.

I am comparing the contents of each file. If there's a match, I would like to print it. However, my current code keeps returning null and I don't know why. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
  Scanner stdin1 = new Scanner("file1.txt");
  Scanner stdin2 = new Scanner("file2.txt");

  while(stdin1.hasNext()){
     while(stdin2.hasNext()){
        if(stdin1.next().equals(stdin2.next()){
           //This line below is giving the error
           System.out.println(stdin1.next() + " " + stdin2.next() );
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: See the documentation for next() : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next() . You are calling it two times. One in `if` and the other one in `System.out.println`

Comment: It isn't. This code should throw `NoSuchElementException`, not get a `null` from `Scanner.next()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `hasNext()` method checks whether there are anymore elements or not. If it returns true, then it means that there is one more element which you can access using `next()` method.

In your code, for every `hasNext()`, you are calling `next()` two times which is not the correct way.

You should modify your code to somewhat like this:

```
  Scanner stdin1 = new Scanner("file1.txt");
  Scanner stdin2 = new Scanner("file2.txt");

  while(stdin1.hasNext()){
     while(stdin2.hasNext()){
        Object one = stdin1.next();
        Object two = stdin2.next();

        if(one.equals(two)){
           //This line below is giving the error
           System.out.println(one + " " + two );
         }
      }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Note that `next()` doesn't returns null if there's no next token. This technique is to deal with the error `java.util.NoSuchElementException` which is thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that there are no more elements in the enumeration. [[source]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)

Comment: You beat me to my answer! :)

Comment: All true, but calling `next()` twice doesn't cause it to return null. Nothing does.

Answer (score 1):

I realized what you are trying to achieve is not what you are doing in your code.

The constructor `Scanner(String source)` does not take a File Name as input.

Use this constructor instead: `Scanner(File file)`

To achieve what you are doing, try this:

> Update: The scanner object needs to be closed and re-opened inside the inner while loop, which is a unnecessary overhead due to multiple i/o operations. To avoid this, capture the elements into a list and then do the comparison. Try this piece of code:

```
    Scanner stdin1 = new Scanner(new File("file1.txt"));
    Scanner stdin2 = new Scanner(new File("file2.txt"));

    List list1 = new ArrayList();
    List list2 = new ArrayList();
    while (stdin1.hasNext()) {
        list1.add(stdin1.next());
    }
    while (stdin2.hasNext()) {
        list2.add(stdin2.next());
    }

    for (Object o1 : list1) {
        for (Object o2 : list2) {
            if (o1.equals(o2)) {
                System.out.println(o1 + " " + o2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Try to add an alternate solution. You have the same @rD posted before.

Comment: @Thrasher Yeah. rD beat me to the answer. When I started answering mine was the only answer. But by the time I posted, rD's answer had come in. I'll try to change or delete my post in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

By "returning null" you mean the program prints nothing.

Two problems.

First, `Scanner(String text)` creates a scanner on the given string. **It does not create a scanner to read a file of the given name.** Instead, you should give it a `File`.

```
Scanner stdin1 = new Scanner(new File("file1.txt"));
```

Second, what's with the nested while loop? You should check **both** scanners before extracting tokens from them.

```
while (stdin1.hasNext() && stdin2.hasNext()) {
    String one = stdin1.next();
    String two = stdin2.next();
    if (one.equals(two)) {
        // print
    }
}
// Now maybe one of them still got tokens, but we are printing 
// the tokens that are equal, so doesn't matter.
```

Why your code prints nothing? Because `stdin1.next()` returns `"file1.txt"` and `stdin2.next()` returns `"file2.txt"`.

Answer (score 1):

Two **while loop** is high time complexity, try to solve this with one loop, and close the program after execution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin1 = null, stdin2 = null;
        try {
            stdin1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\pechen\\Documents\\file1.txt"));
            stdin2 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\pechen\\Documents\\file2.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (stdin1.hasNext()) {
            if (stdin2.hasNext()) {
                Object o = stdin1.next();
                if (o.equals(stdin2.next())) {
                    System.out.println(o);
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```